# Playing steam games on from windows 7 ntfs parttion on ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: steam

I have Windows and Ubuntu partitions on my laptop. I tried using Wine to start Steam. It actually works and may function fine. My only problem is when I try to start one of my games, some of them will start. The only game that works so far is Team Fortress 2. The game is a bit slow and when you go to one the battle areas and stutters a little. Is it because of the NTFS on my partition? Or is it because of my graphics card? I have an Icore3 CPU,4 gigs of RAM, and a intel hd 3000 graphics card. Is there some way to improve the performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can pretty positively say it has *nothing* to do with your NTFS partition.

The fact of the matter is that Wine can't run everything. Some games just don't function properly with Wine. Wine runs Windows programs, but it hasn't mastered it yet. Sometimes it just...doesn't work.

Your graphics card (although you don't technically have a card, the Intel HD series is integrated graphics) will affect the speed and sometimes compatability of games as well.

In the meantime, you can try running Steam [*natively on Ubuntu*](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Valve). (TF2 is on here!)